# Problemas no l-i-v-e-w-i-r-e v3

Tags: laravel

Create cliente
    
    
        
            
                Nome:
                
                
                    @error('name')
                        {{ $message }}
                    @enderror

```
        <div class="columns-1 space-y-2 border-b border-gray-900/10 pb-2">
            <label for="email" class="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">E-mail:</label>
            <input wire:model="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="@..." class="block rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 pl-5 pr-20 text-gray-900 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6" autocomplete="email"><br>
            <div>
                @error('email')
                    <span class="">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="space-y-2 border-b border-gray-900/10 pb-2">
            <label for="phone" class="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">Celular:</label>
            <input wire:model="phone" type="text" id="phone" placeholder="(--)---- ----" class="block rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 pl-5 pr-20 text-gray-900 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6" autocomplete="tel-local"><br>
            <div>
                @error('phone')
                    <span class="">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="space-y-2 border-b border-gray-900/10 pb-2">
            <label for="endereco" class="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">Endereço:</label>
            <input wire:model="endereco" type="text" id="endereco"  class="block rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 pl-5 pr-20 text-gray-900 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6" autocomplete="address-level1"><br>
            <div>
                @error('endereco')
                    <span class="">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="space-y-2 border-b border-gray-900/10 pb-2">
            <label for="cpf" class="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">CPF:</label>
            <input wire:model="cpf" type="text" id="cpf" placeholder="***.***.***-**" class="block rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 pl-5 pr-20 text-gray-900 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6" autocomplete="cc-number"><br>
            <div>
                @error('cpf')
                    <span class="">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="space-y-2 border-b border-gray-900/10 pb-2">
            <label for="cep" class="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">CEP:</label> 
            <input wire:model="cep" type="text" id="cep" placeholder="**.***-**" class="block rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 pl-5 pr-20 text-gray-900 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6" autocomplete="cc-number"><br>
            <div>
                @error('cep')
                    <span class="">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="space-y-2 border-b border-gray-900/10 pb-2">
            <label for="cnpj" class="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">CNPJ:</label>
            <input wire:model="cnpj" type="text" id="cnpj" placeholder="**.*** *** **** **" class="block rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 pl-5 pr-20 text-gray-900 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6" autocomplete="cc-number"><br>
            <div>
                @error('cnpj')
                    <span class="">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="justify-end">
            <button wire:click="save" class="font-medium bg-green-600 hover:bg-green-700 rounded-md pr-5 py-2 pl-5 text-white mb-2">Salvar</button><br>
            <p class="font-bold mb-2 text-gray-700">Já possui uma conta?</p> <button wire:navigate href="/login" class="font-medium bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-800 rounded-md pr-5 py-2 pl-5 text-white mb-2">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

esse é um dos arquivos de tela do meu projeto l-i-v-e-w-i-r-e. Fiz a instalação dele normal no meu projeto l-a-r-a-v-e-l x10 através de curso no Youtube. Meu problema é que nenhum dos comandos w-i-r-e:... nos botões, por exemplo, está funcionando, Preciso de ajuda! na parte do design, estou utilizando T-a-i-l-w-i-n-d

Comment: Considerando que [esta pergunta já foi feita e orientações já foram passadas](/q/591228/70) os comentários foram desativados nesta postagem para evitar descentralização de informações, mas continua disponível na postagem original. Queira melhorar aquela postagem conforme sugerido.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Verifique se o Livewire está sendo carregado corretamente ao acessar uma página via rota do Livewire, especialmente na versão 3 onde o carremento automatico, insira o seguinte script no final do seu arquivo Blade, antes do fechamento da tag `</body>`. Isso permitirá testar o Livewire diretamente pelo console do navegador:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        if (window.Livewire) {
            console.log('Livewire está carregado e pronto!');

        } else {
            console.error('Livewire não está carregado!');
        }
    });

</script>
```

Se o Livewire não estiver sendo carregado automaticamente, você deve incluir @livewireStyles no `<head>` e @livewireScripts antes do fechamento da tag `</body>` em seu layout Blade.